# Blender Cycles render engine times out and stops rendering after a while with a "cancel" error message in the top left of the viewport?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I was on here a couple weeks ago and my problem was not fixed and im wondering if anyone still has any idea what this could be its something to do with my GPU and blender not working together.

[image]

It would be great if someone knows this issue because right now im unable to render anything with blender.

---

Relevant error messages from the debug log:

```
CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS in cuStreamSynchronize(cuda_stream[thread_index]) (device_optix.cpp:769)

Refer to the Cycles GPU rendering documentation for possible solutions:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS in cuStreamSynchronize(cuda_stream[thread_index]) (device_optix.cpp:769)

Refer to the Cycles GPU rendering documentation for possible solutions:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html
```

[...]

```
Illegal address in cuMemFree(mem.device_pointer) (device_cuda_impl.cpp:964)
Illegal address in cuMemFree(mem.device_pointer) (device_cuda_impl.cpp:964)
Illegal address in cuGraphicsUnregisterResource(pmem.cuPBOresource) (device_cuda_impl.cpp:2193)
Illegal address in cuGraphicsUnregisterResource(pmem.cuPBOresource) (device_cuda_impl.cpp:2193)
Illegal address in cuMemFree(mem.device_pointer) (device_cuda_impl.cpp:964)
```

System Information

- Operating System: Windows
- Graphics Card: 2x GeForce RTX 2080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 4.5.0 NVIDIA 452.06

Comment: If you're using Windows you might have exceeded the TDR delay and the OS reset the graphics card.

Comment: We'd have to see a debug log for the GPU, system information and an error message to identify the cause. Open Blender's installation directory, double click on `blender_debug_gpu.cmd`, repeat the steps to make Cycles cancel the render then close Blender. The Windows Explorer should open and show you two files. One is for the system information the other is the debug log.

Comment: how should i upload these .txt documents?

Comment: I would suggest you upload them to e.g. Google Drive and link them. I can extract the relevant parts for you and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: ok sounds good i will do that now

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cF9ENH70qEVK5dVXezIpj2gL3JTxUbZM?usp=sharing

Hopefully these are what you are looking for :D

Comment: The content is not publicly accessible, you would need to change the permissions.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cF9ENH70qEVK5dVXezIpj2gL3JTxUbZM?usp=sharing

Comment: i changed the permission to anyone with the link

Comment: Based on the error message I would first try to [increase the TDR delay](https://docs.substance3d.com/spdoc/gpu-drivers-crash-with-long-computations-128745489.html) to rule it out as possible cause and if this doesn't solve it, report it on the bug tracker.

Comment: what recommended delay would you suggest?

Comment: Thank you by the way for helping me

Comment: I would go with the 60s (`3C` in hex) as the article suggests. That should be high enough.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it doesnt work im affraid so i have now taken it to the bug reports

Comment: That is unfortunate. Please use Help > Report a bug in Blender and attach the debug log to your report by dragging and dropping it on the report or by clicking on the upload icon.