# Blender Cycles rendering with GPU freezes (2.90) can someone point me to a guy who actually knows what the errors mean

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

Hi i have 2 rtx 2080ti and this issue has been going on for over a month. the cycles render engine pops up with an "illegal cuda error message" or sometimes it doesn't even mention the error it just freezes when i try to render in cycles. i have reported it twice to the developers and twice on here but no one has any idea on how to fix it. i gave the bug team all the debug info they need and they never solved it just saying it could be driver updates. does anyone know anyone smart enough to fix this issue? because i have no clue at this point and cycles hasn't been working for properly for 4 weeks now.

[image]

Comment: Please link the bug report ticket. Have you tried to increase the TDR delay?

Comment: hello i have spoken to you about this twice before and both times you have sent me to report a bug i donee that and done everything they said but they say they cant fix it because they dont really care by what i can gather, its low priority. and they say there is no issue? but there clearly is.

Comment: You're right, I've just checked your older questions. Could you still post a link to your bug reports? It looks like the [first issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192361/cycles-render-is-rendering-everything-transparent) you've posted is gone now, since in your [second one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193558/blender-cycles-render-engine-times-out-and-stops-rendering-after-a-while-with-a) you are able to render something except that you run into the CUDA error. Is that right or was the first just limited to the viewport?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cF9ENH70qEVK5dVXezIpj2gL3JTxUbZM?usp=sharing

Comment: these are the two txt documents they asked for at the time

Comment: I know about those files, you've already linked them in your previous question. You said you've reported the issue to the developers, please post the link to the tickets on the [bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/). This avoids asking the same questions again or chasing down a path that was already checked. Just as clarification, in case it hasn't been clear, Blender's StackExchange (this website) is *not* the bug tracker and most people here aren't Blender developers, just users helping other users.

Comment: sorry what des that mean?

Comment: i dont know what tickets are

Comment: A ticket is created when you report a bug in Blender on the [bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/). You can do this directly on the website by filling out the [submission template](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/) or through *Help > Report a bug* in Blender. The latter is preferred because it automatically fills in your system information. Have you done this in the past? If yes, then please post a link to it.

Comment: So far we think it is a hardware issue but i cant find anything wrong with my graphics cards and i tried everything that they suggested this was our talk
https://developer.blender.org/T80381 im still not sure if this is what you wanted but yeah hopefully it is? Im really not that good with computers which is why im asking for help but if there is anything i can do i will try my best to do it.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to. I will take a look, but can't promise that I'll find a solution.

Comment: Do these freezes also occur when you're using CUDA instead of OptiX?

Comment: yes they do it pops up as a cuda error message but i can no longer even re create the error messages it will just freeze with no warning

Comment: Have you checked what happens when you unplug one of the GPUs?

Comment: no i will try that now, should i plug it back in after?